# Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, integers

Let $A,B$ be a $\gamma$-bit integer and relatively prime. $\gcd(A,B)=1$. Also, $A-B \ge 2^{\gamma -2}$

Then, by the Euclidean Algorithm, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that

$Ax-By = 1$. After then, what is the size of $T=|y A -x B|$? Can we find upper bound of T?

Comment: These $x$ and $y$ are not unique. Depending on which ones you choose, the answer might vary. Do you want $x+y$ to be minimal, $y-x$ minimal,...?

Comment: @Bemte. um.. I just want to minimize a T. Is it dependency to $y-x$?

Comment: How to minimize $x+y$?

Answer (score 0):

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108601/estimates-for-bezout-coefficients

See the above link

By this we know $|x|\leq B$ and $|y|\leq A$

Now we know for two reals c,d we have $|c-d|\geq {\bigg |}|c|-|d|{\bigg |}$.

so you can find a lower bound of $|yA−xB|$ using the above inequality and as of the upper bound it is clearly less than or equal to $A^2+B^2$ (As we know the bounds of $x$ and $y$)

Comment: Thanks you, but it would be a rough bound.

Comment: Yep, i don't think explicit bounds is easy to find, i think you might find the order of the bounds